# Concatenate 2 arrays with object in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following array

```
var x = [{"id":"757382348857","title":"title","handle":"linkhere","productimage":"url","ippid":true,"location_x":26,"location_y":18}]
```

And i am trying to add the following array into it

```
var y = [{"id":"75769d11","title":"newtitle"}]
```

What i am trying to do is to merge somehow the 2 arrays into 1.
The final array should be

```
[{"id":"757382348857","title":"title","handle":"linkhere","productimage":"url","ippid":true,"location_x":26,"location_y":18},{"id":"75769d11","title":"newtitle"}]
```

Have tried

```
$.merge(x,y) 
// x.join(y) 
// x.push(y)
```

javascript

```
x.concat(y)
```

Any idea would be useful.
Regards

Comment: Use  `x.push(y[0])`

Comment: `x.concat(y)` worked for me. What is the issue?

Comment: These arrays are strings , so i think that is why i can't concat them or push, as it seems it gives error. Think i need to transform from string into array ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, `Array.concat()` method returns a new merged array. So, you have to store it in a variable to log it:

```js
var x = [{"id":"757382348857","title":"title","handle":"linkhere","productimage":"url","ippid":true,"location_x":26,"location_y":18}]

var y = [{"id":"75769d11","title":"newtitle"}]

var merged = x.concat(y);

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 3):

using **jQuery**

```
 var x = [{"id":"757382348857","title":"title","handle":"linkhere","productimage":"url","ippid":true,"location_x":26,"location_y":18}]
 var y = [{"id":"75769d11","title":"newtitle"}];
 var mergedArray=$.merge(x,y);
 var mergedString=JSON.stringify(mergedArray);
 console.log(mergedString);
```

Comment: using jQuery without referencing, assuming everybody uses jQ?

Answer (score 2):

`var newArray=x.concat(y)` will work.

With `ES6`, You can also use spread operator `...`. Spread operator turns the items of an iterable(arrays, array like objects) into arguments of a function call or into elements of an Array.
So, to get new merged array you can do

`var newArray=[...x, ...y]`

If you want to merge the elements of `x` and `y` into `x`, you can still use spread operator as `x.push(...y)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = [{"id":"757382348857","title":"title","handle":"linkhere","productimage":"url","ippid":true,"location_x":26,"location_y":18}]

var y = [{"id":"75769d11","title":"newtitle"}]

var merged = x.concat(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mergedArray = [...x, ...y];
```

Comment: I will upvote, if you elaborate your answer with helpful links and demo. This would not help OP to understand what is spread syntax

Comment: please explain your answer